# How to link and display MySQL data from two different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

I have two tables named "stats" and "users"

users table has all the typical user data like id,username,password,email(columns) 
stats table has id,attack, defense,ostats,gold,food(columns)

I want to display data from these two tables side by side and have the data linked through their IDS
For example,

```
 Rank   user_uid   ostats     attack    defense    gold 
   1    Test        10          5         5        100
   2    Test2       8           2         6        60
   3    Test3       6           5         1        40
```

Username is from table "users" and the rest of them are from table "stats" 
So first I want to know how to link and display the data from the same ID, like Username(user_id=1) and ostats,attack,defense,gold,food(id=1)

Then I want them in order by their "ostats" (I don't have a column named "rank" in any table yet, just don't know how to create the rank using overall stats)

Comment: Can you edit with a table schema ?

Comment: you can use join for fetching data from two tables with common column id.

Comment: what is common in between two tables? `user_id`?

Comment: They don't have any column name in common, because stats has user_uid(instead of just id, I could always change that if needed) but the values of user_uid from table "users" and id from table "stats" are the ones in common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like (untested)

```
SELECT u.username, s.overall, s.attack, s.defense, s.gold 
FROM stats s JOIN users u on s.user_uid = u.id 
ORDER BY s.overall;
```

Possible solution to ranking:

```
set @row_number=0;
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number+1) as rank, u.username, s.overall, s.attack, s.defense, s.gold 
FROM stats s JOIN users u on s.user_uid = u.id 
ORDER BY s.overall;
```

Another, horrible looking attempt:

```
set @row_number = (select count(*) from users) + 1;
select (@row_number:=@row_number-1) as rank,  u.username, s.overall from 
stats s join users u on s.user_uid = u.id order by s.overall desc;
set @row_number = 0;
```

Here in PHP code, you have to run it as two queries to set the variable, then run the actual ranking query. This way, the rank variable is always set to 0 when running this. Note that I've used different table and column names, just to simplify things a little. Remember to adjust to your specific needs.

```
// connect to database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
// this query will set a variable to 0.
$setSql = "SET @row_number = 0;";
// run the query. This will return a boolean - true or false, depending on whether or not the query ran successfully
$variableSet = mysqli_query($conn, $setSql);
// if the query ran successfully
if($variableSet){
    // setup the actual ranking query
    $statsSql = "select 
                     (@row_number:=@row_number+1) as rank,
                     u.id,
                     u.username,
                     s.overall
                 from
                     mstats s 
                 join 
                     musers u
                 on 
                     s.muser = u.id
                 order by 
                     s.overall desc;";
    $ranks = mysqli_query($conn, $statsSql);
    if(!$ranks){
        // dump error from rank query
        var_dump($conn->error); 
    } else {
        // dump results as associative array
        var_dump($ranks->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    }
} else {
    // dump errors from setting variable
    var_dump($conn->error); 
}
```

For me, the results dump looks like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'rank' => string '1' (length=1)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'username' => string 'Bar' (length=3)
      'overall' => string '1000' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'rank' => string '2' (length=1)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'username' => string 'Tom' (length=3)
      'overall' => string '7' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'rank' => string '3' (length=1)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'username' => string 'Foo' (length=3)
      'overall' => string '3' (length=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is working smooth. They're all arranged in order by "ostats(overall)" now. But how I do get the ranks for each user? I mean they're arranged in the order of 1,2,3...and so on but the rank isn't visible yet. How do I make it visible in a number format too?

Comment: Updated the answer with a way to rank/enumerate results now, @i0N77

Comment: This might not play nice with the ORDER BY though.. We have to go deeper

Comment: I've added my response as a new answer just so I could get it in a 'code format' ..Please check and tell what I need to fix..

Comment: I've tried it out and updated my answer too, Please check and tell what me went wrong with it @Kyrre